# Is there a way to full load once after setting incremental refresh in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi

I set up incremental refresh in powerBI, and it loaded all the history to the service, and now only refreshes the last data every time, as expected. I need to reload once all the history, because of changes made to historical data. Is there a way to do so?

If I republish my dataset from PowerBI desktop to the service, the data will be reloaded fully. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is NOT in a Premium workspace, republishing is your only option.

If your model is published to a Premium workspace, you can manage the underlying data through the XMLA endpoint. You have to have that set up to be writable in your Power BI Admin settings. Once it's open, you can manage IR models with SQL Server Management Studio ([MS doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-xmla)). There are also some third-party tools. Of these, Tabular Editor is the best. [This is a video](https://youtu.be/icCGFG6KpIA) from Guy in a Cube that will get you started with TE.

If you have Premium, I highly recommend setting up all your IR tables as Dataflows. That separates the IR from your report, and makes managing IR much simpler in the long run. IR Dataflows are not available without Premium.

Answer (score 1):

> If I republish my dataset from PowerBI desktop to the service, the data will be reloaded fully. Is there a simpler solution?

Simpler, no.  But you can force a full refresh with the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/asynchronous-refresh).

> applyRefreshPolicy    Boolean true
>
> If an incremental refresh policy is defined, applyRefreshPolicy will
> determine if the policy is applied or not. If the policy isn't
> applied, a process full operation will leave partition definitions
> unchanged and all partitions in the table will be fully refreshed.
> Modes are true or false.